# discontiguous not recognized when its inside an included file

Tags: prolog

I am using SWI Prolog 7.4.2 and I am getting warnings from SWI prolog about clauses not being together even though I have declared discontiguous at the top of the file, when the file is included

so if test1.pro contains

```
:- discontiguous(p/0).
p :- q.
q.
p.
```

and I consult this file I get no complaints, but when I have test2.pro

```
:- include("test1.pro").
```

and load test2.pro then I get complaints about the clauses of p not being together

Comment: Start SWI anew and say `compile('test2.pro').` I do not see any errors here neither with 7.5.1 nor 7.3.1. I suspect that you said `compile('test1.pro').` and then `compile('test2.pro')` which produces errors as this does not make sense!

Comment: OK so the problem was that the database had got really butchered by several attempts to get this right. I was able to get it to work right by quitting prolog and restarting. In general, I find it odd that SWI Prolog has no command to clear the database of all user defined knowledge.